# How to Separate or Propagate Limonium Perezii aka: Statice?

Tags: seeds, germination, propagation, overseeding

I have an overgrown limonium perezii that I want to propagate it to the nearby areas. I tried cutting a branch (without any root) and planting it into moist soil. That didn't work. I also tried just spreading the withered flowers (seeds) onto bare soil. That didn't work either.

Can anyone suggest the most effective ways to separate or propagate it?

Picture reference: [image: limonium perezii]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three different ways to propagate this plant - if the clump is very large, you can dig it up in spring, split it and replant the section/s. Otherwise, you can try semi ripe cuttings, in mid to late summer, from non flowering shoots, some instructions in the link below

http://www.garden.org/regional/report/arch/inmygarden/200

Otherwise, collect the seed when it forms, removing husks and dried bits from the flowers, and sow where they are to flower outdoors, or, more successful, ensure the seed is dry, contain it in some foil and then a plastic bag, or just in a sealed plastic bag, pop it in the fridge to store the seed over winter, and start off indoors the following year 6-8 weeks before you want to plant them out.

Comment: The clump is not large enough to be separated from the root. There is only one main trunk connecting the roots. But I will try collecting the seeds using your method. Thank you.